# octobercms change style of login page

Tags: authentication, backend, octobercms

I use this code to change font of backend but login page font not change,

```
Event::listen('backend.page.beforeDisplay', function($controller, $action, $params) {
    $controller->addCss('/plugins/myname/myplugin/assets/css/mustyle.css');
});
```

how I can inject CSS file in auth page?

Answer (score 0):

`backend.page.beforeDisplay` event doesn't get triggered on login page.

You basically have 3 options:

1. Simply add your custom CSS in the backend branding settings ("Styles" tab). These styles will be included in the signin page as well.
2. Use `'backend.auth.extendSigninView'` to add your style at the bottom of the signin page:

```
Event::listen('backend.auth.extendSigninView', function ($controller, $firstParam) {
    return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/plugins/myname/myplugin/assets/css/mustyle.css">';
});
```

3. Use `'backend.layout.extendHead'` in a similar way to put the style in your head, passing 'auth.htm' as layout param